# d3 v4 schemeBlues undefined property

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was trying to create a color gradient function:

```
var blues = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeBlues[9]);
```

But received errors on the console pointing to that `9`, saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '9')
```

I am referencing `v4` of the d3: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>`. The fact that that color gradient [I was trying to use](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic/commit/2aa3ad24197136a5adeb1647502270dba5d74668) is in `v3` makes me doubt if it's an issue with the version. But I also used `d3.geoAlbersUsa()` in the same script, which does not seem to work in `v3`.

Exactly why is `schemeBlues` not working? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color schemes are not included in the D3 default bundle in version 4.
You must include an additional library:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
```

However, in latest version of D3 (version 7), it is included by default.